# mysqli: Is it possible to create or update a table that adds up other tables?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a meals table that displays a list of meals: Tacos, Hamburgers, Sandwiches, ect. Then I have another table that is the ingredients per each meal. Meat, Cheese, Lettuce, Tomatoes, ect.

So inside my Meals Table, I have a total number of ingredients. For example's sake, lets say sandwiches, which will have a total number of ingredients 5. Now I could manually enter 5, but the user is imputing a unknown variable of ingredients. So I want to say, for every ingredient added, the value of ingredients in meals gets +1 added to it.

I set the relationship between these 2 tables as many2many, but how do I do algorithmic calculations?

Here is what I have so far:

```
if (isset($_POST['add_ingredient'])){
    $meal = (string)$_POST['meal_names'];
    $ingr = (string)$_POST['ingredients_list'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO meal_ingredients (quanity, package, cost, store)
        SELECT quanity, package, cost, store
        FROM ingredients
        WHERE item='$ingr'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. </br>";
    }   
    else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>"  . $conn->error;
    }

$sql = "UPDATE meal_ingredients
        SET meal_name='$meal', item='$ingr'
        WHERE meal_ingredients_id=$last_id";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully.";
    }   
    else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>"  . $conn->error;
    }

$sql = "UPDATE meals
    SET ingredients='1'
    WHERE meal='$meal'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Updated Meal";
}   
else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>"  . $conn->error;
}
```

}